# Events for Long click down and long click up in Android

Tags: android, android-button

I want two separate event for long click Down and Long click up. How can I do this in Android?

What I have tried is as follows

```
public class FfwRewButton extends ImageButton {

    public interface ButtonListener {

        void OnLongClickDown(View v);

        void OnLongClickUp(View v);
    }

    private ButtonListener mListener;

    private boolean mLongClicked = false;

    public FfwRewButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setFocusable(true);
        setLongClickable(true);
    }

    public FfwRewButton(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public FfwRewButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, android.R.attr.imageButtonStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyLongPress(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        Log.d("my listener", "long press");
        mLongClicked = true;
        mListener.OnLongClickDown(this);
        return super.onKeyLongPress(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        Log.d("my listener", "key down");
        mLongClicked = false;
        if (true) {
            super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        Log.d("my listener", "key up");
        if (mLongClicked)
            mListener.OnLongClickUp(this);
        return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
    }

    public void setFfwRewButtonListener(ButtonListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }
}
```

and in an activity I called it like this

```
private FfwRewButton.ButtonListener mListener = new FfwRewButton.ButtonListener() {

        @Override
        public void OnLongClickUp(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "longClickup");
        }

        @Override
        public void OnLongClickDown(View v) {
            Log.d(TAG, "longClickdown");
        }
    };
```

But still  am not getting any of the Log messages in logcat
Can anyone help me; where I am wrong ?

Comment: by onLongClickUp do you mean when a user lifts their finger after longClicking?

Comment: yes, when user lifts  finger

Comment: Use touch events instead of Key events

Comment: how would i know if its a long ckick in Touch events ?

Comment: manually keep track of time to determine if it is down for 500ms (which is roughly the amount of time the system considers to be a long click

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`onKeyXXX()` methods are for Key Events from keyboard or hard keys such as menu key, search key, and so on.

If you want to detect touch events, which is called `MotionEvent` in Android, you have to override `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e)` method and use `GestureDetector` class for identifying long press.

```
private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

public FfwRewButton(...) {
    //....
    mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, 
        new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
                mLongClicked = false;
                return true;
            }
            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                mLongClicked = true;
                // long press down detected
            }
        });
    }

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e);
        if (mLongClicked && e.getAction() == ACTION_UP) {
           // long press up detected
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: something like this is probably better than what I proposed since it uses a real listener to pick up the normal long click instead of relying on manually tracking the time like mine did.

Comment: how to connect my button to this gesturedetector ?

Comment: It is already connected. If you look at the onTouchEvent() method in your FfwRewButton class, it calls onTouchEvent() method of the GestureDetector object.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this will get you on the right path,

I didn't compile so you may have to correct a few syntax things but your goal can be achieved with this concept

```
OnTouchListener mTouchListener = new OnTouchListener(){
  private totalTimeDown = -1;
  private downTime = -1;
  public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent me){
    if(me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        downTime = System.getCurrentTimeInMillis();
        return true;
    }

    if(me.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
        totalTimeDown = System.getCurrentTimeInMillis() - downTime;
        if(totalTimeDown > 500){
            //Finger was down long enough for "longClick"
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
holder.layout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch(event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                holder.layoutItem.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                holder.layoutDelete.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }
                        }, 1000);
                        // PRESSED
                        return true; // if you want to handle the touch event
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        holder.layoutItem.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        holder.layoutDelete.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        // RELEASED
                        return true; // if you want to handle the touch event
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this solution to detect the Gesture

```
val gestureDetector = GestureDetector(context, object : GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            override fun onSingleTapConfirmed(e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
                // Perform single click
                return true
            }

            override fun onLongPress(e: MotionEvent) {
                // Perform your action on long press
                super.onLongPress(e)
            }
        })
```

Now, set your gesture to touch the listener of the view

```
holder.itemView.setOnTouchListener(View.OnTouchListener { view, e ->
            gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e)
            if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
             //Perform your action when the user takes their finger off
            }
            return@OnTouchListener true
        })
```