# Combining Next and Forward function as one button in android eclipse

Tags: android, audio-player, onlongclicklistener, android-music-player

I am creating an android music player.I am going to make both the Next and Forward button work in one button depending on the duration it's held down. In a short press it works as the Next button and in long press it works as the forward button. I have tried this using onLongClickListener but what happen is, it stops forwarding even before the user holds up the button. How do I implement it in the way where the action doesn't stop till the user hold up the button? Here is my code. Thanks in advanced.

```
        btnNext.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View arg0) {
            // get current song position
            int currentPosition = mp.getCurrentPosition();

            // check if seekForward time is lesser than song duration
            if (currentPosition + seekForwardTime <= mp.getDuration()) {
                // forward song
                mp.seekTo(currentPosition + seekForwardTime + LONG_CLICK_LISTERNER_INTERVAL);
            } else {
                // forward to end position
                mp.seekTo(mp.getDuration());
            }
            return true;

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

See this post of mine [Events for Long click down and long click up in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14877009/events-for-long-click-down-and-long-click-up-in-android)

If you want to detect touch events, which is called MotionEvent in Android, you have to override onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) method and use GestureDetector class for identifying long press.

```
private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;

public FfwRewButton(...) {
    //....
    mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, 
        new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
                mLongClicked = false;
                return true;
            }
            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                mLongClicked = true;
                // long press down detected
            }
    });
}

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
    mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e);
    if (mLongClicked && e.getAction() == ACTION_UP) {
           // long press up detected
        }
    }
}
```

on long press down you can start a thread doing same in a loop and stop on long press up , hope this helps you