# Parent click event not firing when recyclerview clicked

Tags: android, android-cardview, android-recyclerview

I have a RecyclerView which is in a CardView that has a couple of TextViews.  The CardView has a `OnClickListener` set and is fired off when clicking on the TextViews, but does not fire when clicking on the RecyclerView.

Here is what the CardView looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="5dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="100"
        android:minWidth="100dp">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:textColor="@color/abc_primary_text_material_light"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:listSelector="@color/highlighted_text_material_light"
            android:layout_weight="98" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="@android:color/black" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/relativeSummary"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:id="@+id/text2"
                android:textAlignment="viewEnd"
                android:textColor="@color/abc_secondary_text_material_light"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:gravity="start"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:id="@+id/text3"
                android:textColor="@color/abc_primary_text_material_light"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/text2" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

I do not need a click listener on this RecyclerView and really only need the parent view's click event to fire when the RecyclerView is clicked (The same goes for the OnLongClick event).  I also need the RecyclerView to scroll.  Is the RecyclerView some how eating the click event and not passing it up to the parent?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There is a better solution. That is, subclass your `CardView`:

```
public class InterceptTouchCardView extends CardView {

    public InterceptTouchCardView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public InterceptTouchCardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public InterceptTouchCardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    /**
     * Intercept touch event so that inner views cannot receive it.
     * 
     * If a ViewGroup contains a RecyclerView and has an OnTouchListener or something like that,
     * touch events will be directly delivered to inner RecyclerView and handled by it. As a result, 
     * parent ViewGroup won't receive the touch event any longer.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16):

```
recyclerView.setLayoutFrozen(true);
```

just setLayoutFrozen true after setAdapter for recyclerView

Comment: This method prevents RecyclerView from being updated — adapter's `onBindViewHolder` wont be called in some circumstances.

Comment: This disables scroll event.

Comment: the won't refresh item layout when recycle. should not use this in a list which item contain another recyclerView.

Comment: `setLayoutFrozen` is deprecated so use `supressLayout(true)` if you literally only need to show data in a recycler without anything else (scroll, click...etc)

Answer (score 12):

In my case, I had a CardView with a couple of buttons and a RecyclerView. With the solutions of [ywwynm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32663194/1680301) and [Daryl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34604039/1680301) the problem was that the CardView would intercept the events from all of its children views, including the buttons. But what I wanted was for the CardView to intercept the touch events of the RecyclerView only. My solution was the following:

```
public class UntouchableRecyclerView extends RecyclerView {

    public UntouchableRecyclerView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public UntouchableRecyclerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public UntouchableRecyclerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer George, By default Recyclerview-OnTouchevents returns true when the layout is not frozen means it handles. With this case, touch event is completely disabled.

Comment: Perfect solution!!

Comment: This disables scroll event.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out how to get the click event to the RecyclerView's parent.  My solution kind of feels like a hack, so I'm hoping that someone can come up with a better solution.

In the RecylerView.Adapter:

```
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(final ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.my_item_layout, viewGroup, false);

    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);

    viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            viewGroup.callOnClick();
        }
    });
    viewHolder.itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            return viewGroup.performLongClick();
        }
    });

    return viewHolder;
}
```

I then had to hook up the click event on the RecyclerView:

```
RecyclerView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        parentView.callOnClick();
    }
});
RecyclerView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        return parentView.performLongClick();
    }
});
```

Comment: This works, but it doesn't show the clicking effect of the ViewGroup.

Answer (score 2):

@ywwynm, you are on the right track except the solution doesn't allow the nested RecyclerView to scroll.  I combined it with the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14877384/803349) and came up with this solution to handle click and onLongClick events as well as to allow scrolling.

```
public class InterceptTouchCardView extends CardView {
    private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;
    private boolean mLongClicked;

    public InterceptTouchCardView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        Initialize();
    }

    public InterceptTouchCardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        Initialize();
    }

    public InterceptTouchCardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        Initialize();
    }

    private void Initialize() {
        mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(getContext(),
                new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
                    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
                        mLongClicked = false;
                        return true;
                    }

                    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                        mLongClicked = true;
                        performLongClick();
                    }
                });
    }

    /**
     * Intercept touch event so that inner views cannot receive it.
     *
     * If a ViewGroup contains a RecyclerView and has an OnTouchListener or something like that,
     * touch events will be directly delivered to inner RecyclerView and handled by it. As a result,
     * parent ViewGroup won't receive the touch event any longer.
     *
     * We can't Intercept the touch event if we want to allow scrolling since ACTION_DOWN always
     * happens before ACTION_MOVE.  So handle touch events here since onTouchEvent won't be triggered.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
        if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP && !mLongClicked)
            this.callOnClick();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: The downside of this approach is that the selector of the CardView won't be used anymore, thus any feedback of the CardView won't be shown.

Comment: It also consume clicks that should go the RecyclerView items.