# How to make a RecyclerView not clickable and pass onClick event to parent view?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

Is it possible to make a `RecyclerView` not clickable? I want this because my `RecyclerView` just shows some small icons, within a **clickable** `CardView`. So if someone taps the icons, it should just click (and animate) the parent `CardView` instead.

**I have tried the following:**

1. `recyclerView.setClickable(false);`
2. `recyclerView.setFocusable(false);`
3. Extend `RecyclerView` and make `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent)` return `false`.
4. Use method 3 above and use `itemView.setClickable(false);` in the `RecyclerView` Adapter. This works, the click is sent to the parent. However, now the `RecyclerView` is not scrollable anymore.
5. Set `clickable="false"`, `focusable="false"`, `focusableInTouchMode="false"` in inflated list item XML. (See comment *@Ibrahim*)
6. Call `recyclerView#setLayoutFrozen(true)` and `itemView.setClickable(false);`. This works, but has the same issue as #4.

Any ideas how to disable and pass through the click events of the `RecyclerView` to the parent view? Note that the `RecyclerView` still needs to be scrollable (horizontal).

**EDIT:**
User [@c.dunlap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45290379/4583267) suggested to set OnClick listeners to the icons, and just "redirect" the click to the parent's click action. This would work, but there won't be a click animation on the parent view. And if someone clicks outside an itemView - but still inside the `RecyclerView` (e.g. ItemDecoration padding) - the click is not detected. So unfortunately this is not a solution.

Comment: What is code for adapter?

Comment: @VladoPandžić The adapter really doesn't have anything special. It inflates the layout as normal. The only code within `onBindViewHolder(...)` is setting a Drawable to the `ImageView`.

Comment: did  you tried to set `clickable` ,`focusable` and focusableontouchmode false in inflated layout xml?

Comment: @Ibrahim Just tried, didn't make a difference.

Comment: Also try **clickable="false"**, **focusable="false"**, **focusableInTouchMode="false**" on recycle **xml** , and provide the recycle view click implementaion if avilable

Comment: @Ibrahim Did you read my question? See item 1 and 2. Could you explain what a RecyclerView click implementation is?

Comment: Can you share your codes so we can reproduce your problem?

Comment: @FelipeCastilhos You can try it for yourself. It is really easy. Just put a `RecyclerView` inside a clickable `CardView`.

Comment: If you capture the touchEvent it will block the scroll, even if you embed your listview in wrap_content into a scrollview (Yeah I tried for science). I haven't any solution for now. I have created a repo to try this. https://github.com/vdubedout/non-clickable-recyclerview

Comment: @ThomasVos were you ever able to find a solution for this one? Running into the same issue myself. Thanks!

Comment: @Aneem I didn't find a solution yet, but I haven't looked at this issue in the past few months. In my project, a non scrolling list is good enough for now. However, if you find a solution, please share it!

Answer (score 18):

You should extend the parent View and intercept the click, so the recyclerview doesn't receive it.

```
@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    return true;
}
```

Credits to: [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32663194/1652657)

Comment: This is the best working solution. It should be marked as answer

Comment: Wouldn't this prevent scrolling in the RecyclerView?

Answer (score 3):

My preferred way of handling things like this is to attach a listener from your adapter that will be called when each icon in your recycler view is clicked. Then your activity can respond in the appropriate way. For instance:

```
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    private MyAdapterListener mListener;

    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
         holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 mListener.iconClicked();
             }
         });
    }

    public void setListener(MyAdapterListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    public interface MyAdapterListener {
        void iconClicked();
    }

}
```

Then in your activity, you can simply create an instance of MyAdapterListener and set it as the listener for your Recycler View's adapter. Then when `iconClicked()` function is triggered, execute the code that would be executed on parent click.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This would work but there won't be a click animation on the parent view. Also, what if someone clicks outside an `itemView`? How should I handle the click?

Comment: Please see the EDIT part of my question.

Comment: If you modify your itemViews so that they do not have any spacing between them in the recycler view, but instead having padding inside of the itemView, then your itemViews will fill the recyclerView making it impossible to click on the recyclerView but not an item view. If you are doing something else that makes this unfeasible, you will likely need to share your layouts so that we can help you further. Personally, I find that this method typically leads to nicer layouts as well (even spacing between cells).

Comment: The problem is not that there is space in-between the itemViews. Like you said, I can work around that by using padding within the itemView layouts. The problem is that if there are just a few "icons", then not the whole RecyclerView is used, and there is still space left. I can't set the RecyclerView to wrap_content because it needs to be in-between two other views. So I don't think your answer will work for my situation. Any ideas for other solutions?

Comment: Can you share your layout?

Comment: This won't allow clicking effect on the parent of the RecyclerView.

Answer (score -2):

I had same issue, after i trying much more things, i used one more layout over recyclerview.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layoutwidth="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

after that you can visible and gone that "LinearLayout".
This works 100%.

Comment: How does this work? Could you explain how this solves the question?

Comment: When you want make recyclerview desable, you can make visible that LinearLayout, when the LinearLayout will viaible the recyclerview will not work, after that you can gone that LinearLayout for make recyclerview enable.

Comment: Ok, I understand, but that wasn't my question. My question was how to disable the `RecyclerView` **and** pass clicks to the parent view. I also noted the `RecyclerView` still needs to be scrollable.

If I just wanted to disable the `RecyclerView` I could use `setEnabled(false)` on both the `RecyclerView` and the `itemView`s, but then the click won't be passed to the parent layout.

Comment: can you upload your xml, i"ll give proper ans.

Comment: @ThomasVos it works because the LinearLayout masks the whole recyclerview, and receives the clicks instead.