# Click event to parent in a CardView with RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I have a CardView that contains inside a LinearLayout with multiple views,I'd like to have a onClick to whole CardView but RecyclerView has its own and can't pass it to parent view. The layout:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/my_clickable_card"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:duplicateParentState="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_items"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I tried `android:clickable="false"`and`android:focusable="false"` & `android:duplicateParentState="true"` for `RecyclerView` without success.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: did you try `android:clickable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:focusable="true"` in your `CardView`

Comment: @NileshRathod same result

Comment: `RecyclerView has its own` can you show that how you have added click listner to it

Comment: @NileshRathod didn't add `OnClickListener` to the `RecyclerView` (items) at all, only to `CardView`

Comment: SOLUTION: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32663194/3595288 from duplicated question

Answer (score 0):

you have to put cardview in the item layout so with no margins so it looks like the same and there will be no issues of scrolling 
Try to put it in the adapter layout.